# Java: shift negative number

Tags: java

As far as I understand, the result of shifting a positive integer to the left by 1 is the same as multiply it by two.(if it doesn't overflow)

What will happen to a negative integer?

Is x << 1 always equal to x * 2 if it doesn't overflow?

I tried:

```
int num = -1;
for (int i= 0; i < 32; i++){
    System.out.println(num << i);
}
```

It prints

```
-1
-2
-4
-8
-16
-32
-64
-128
-256
-512
-1024
-2048
-4096
-8192
-16384
-32768
-65536
-131072
-262144
-524288
-1048576
-2097152
-4194304
-8388608
-16777216
-33554432
-67108864
-134217728
-268435456
-536870912
-1073741824
-2147483648
```

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question..

Comment: Thanks for editing. So I assume it is always true? not only just for -1.

Comment: @BrendanLong He's only answered it for (negative) powers of 2

Comment: @assylias Given a couple of arithmetic laws, this is sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, bit-shifting to the left by `1` is always equivalent to multiplying by `2` (except for overflow).  The [JLS, Section 15.19](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.19), even says so:

> The value of n << s is n left-shifted s bit positions; this is equivalent (even if overflow occurs) to multiplication by two to the power s.

I think the JLS states "even if overflow occurs" because it's equivalent to the multiply operation which may overflow also.

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit-shift, you should look at what's going on with bits: -1 is 0xFFFFFFFF, after 1 bit shift to left we will get  0xFFFFFFFE it is -2, etc